# Get keys out of array of objects : Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this scenario where I need to fetch only the keys in an array of objects. Object structure is shown below. I have also tried an approach but it does not seem like working. Can someone help me out with this.

```js
var arr = [
        { firstName: "aaaaa", status: 0, visits: 155 },
        { firstName: "aabFaa", status: 0, visits: 155 },
        { firstName: "adaAAaaa", status: 10, visits: 1785 },
        { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: 50, visits: 175 },
        { firstName: "aaaaa", status: 670, visits: 155 },
      ]

console.log([...new Set(arr.map(item => Object.keys(item)))]); //  This does not work
```

I want the output to be just `['firstName','status','visits']`

Comment: What doe you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.keys` does itself return an array, so your `map` creates an array of arrays. Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead:

```
console.log(Array.from(new Set(arr.flatMap(Object.keys))))
```

Alternatively, since all objects in your array have the same keys, you could just take those of the first object:

```
console.log(Object.keys(arr[0]))
```

(this also makes it obvious that the code only works on non-empty arrays)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a `Set` from a 2D array of keys. Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get a flattened array of keys of all the objects in the array

```
[...new Set(arr.flatMap(item => Object.keys(item)))]
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const arr = [
      { firstName: "aaaaa", status: 0, visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "aabFaa", status: 0, visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "adaAAaaa", status: 10, visits: 1785 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: 50, visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "aaaaa", status: 670, visits: 155 },
    ];
    
const uniqueKeys = [...new Set(arr.flatMap(Object.keys))]

console.log(uniqueKeys)
```

Comment: Could be just `flatMap(Object.keys)`

Comment: @georg yeah. I just copied OP's code. And, Bergi has already suggested that.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(arr[0])` is probably the shortest solution, assuming each object in `arr` has the same keys:

```js
var arr = [{
    firstName: "aaaaa",
    status: 0,
    visits: 155
  },
  {
    firstName: "aabFaa",
    status: 0,
    visits: 155
  },
  {
    firstName: "adaAAaaa",
    status: 10,
    visits: 1785
  },
  {
    firstName: "aAaaaa",
    status: 50,
    visits: 175
  },
  {
    firstName: "aaaaa",
    status: 670,
    visits: 155
  },
]

let keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);

console.log(keys);
```